# How do I create a CGImage with RGB data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cgimage

Can anyone show me a clear example of how to use

```
CGImageRef CGImageCreate 
(
   size_t width,
   size_t height,
   size_t bitsPerComponent,
   size_t bitsPerPixel,
   size_t bytesPerRow,
   CGColorSpaceRef colorspace,
   CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo,
   CGDataProviderRef provider,
   const CGFloat decode[],
   bool shouldInterpolate,
   CGColorRenderingIntent intent
);
```

I have a CGFloat dataBuffer [width * height * 3];

It contains all of the RGB data of the image. Essentially, it goes from pixel R (0,0), G (0,0), B(0,0), R(0,1)... to R(width, height), G(width,height), B(width,height)

I know the size of the image, width x height. How do I use the information that I have and create and CGImage??

Please help, thanks

**I posted another question that encompasses the above question. It was answered correctly by nschmidt, here is the link**

[Converting RGB data into a bitmap in Objective-C++ Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579631/converting-rgb-data-into-a-bitmap-in-objective-c-cocoa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I posted another question that encompasses the above question. It was answered correctly by nschmidt, here is the link**

[Converting RGB data into a bitmap in Objective-C++ Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579631/converting-rgb-data-into-a-bitmap-in-objective-c-cocoa)

Answer (score 2):

The biggest mystery there is the data provider. The answer for that is that you need to create a [CGDataProvider](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGDataProvider/) object that either contains or can provide the pixel data you have.

Some lesser mysteries are what to pass for `colorSpace` and `bitmapInfo`. Those are a [CGColorSpace](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcolorspace?language=objc) object and a [CGBitmapInfo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgbitmapinfo?language=objc) bit-mask.

The explanation of the `decode` array could be clearer, but what is clear is that you probably don't need one. Pass `NULL`.

Aside from those things, everything is either self-evident or well-explained in [the documentation for this function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455149-cgimagecreate?language=objc).

Comment: Links are broken.

Comment: searched CGImageCreate on Google, here is the URL popped up: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455149-cgimagecreate?language=objc

Comment: Links are broken :(

Comment: Fixed. Thanks to Chen OT for making it easy to get first to CGImageCreate and then to the rest of the right links.