# Difference between iPAD simulator and device

Tags: uiimage, device, ios-simulator

I've a strange behaviour developing an iPad application (languages: C++/Objective-C): it happens that in the **simulator** everything it's ok, in other words the application run successfully, meanwhile when implementing the program into the **device** I receive an unintelligible EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

This is a chunk of my code in the Obj-C environment:

```
-(void) BindTexture:(unsigned char*)TexBuff {  
    // TexBuff is a fild of a pointer list, containing data prevoisly saved  
    UIImager *texImg = (UIImage*)TexBuff;  
    CGImageRef imageRef = [texImage CGImage];  
    ....  
    .... {so on} ...  
}
```

The device stucks before the call CGImageRef.
The oddities is the difference between Simulator and the Device.
Have you some idea?

Answer (score 0):

You are casting an **unsigned char*** to a **UIImage*** - this is not a good thing to do and is likely the cause of your EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Is TexBuff supposed to be your raw data array? If so, see this post for how to convert raw data (RGBA data for example) into a CGImage:

[Converting RGB data into a bitmap in Objective-C++ Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579631/converting-rgb-data-into-a-bitmap-in-objective-c-cocoa)

Comment: Thanks for the replay. actually the distance from the simulator and device is reduced: the appl doesn't work at all. I'll follow your link and I'll take you tuned, if interested