# NSImage from a 1D pixel array?

Tags: cocoa, image, nsview, nsdata, nsimage

I have a large 1D dynamic array in my program that represents a FITS image on disk i.e. it holds all the pixel values of the image. The type of the array is **double**. At the moment, I am only concerned with monochrome images.

Since Cocoa does not support the FITS format directly, I am reading in the images using the CFITSIO library. This works - I can manipulate the array as I wish and save the result to disk using the library.

However, I now want to display the image. I presume this is something NSImage or NSView can do. But the class references don't seem to list a method which could take a C array and ultimately return an NSImage object. The closest I found was **-initWithData:(NSData*)**. But I'm not 100% sure if this is what I need.

Am I barking up the wrong tree here? Any pointers to a class or method which could handle this would be

EDIT:

Here's the updated code. Note that I'm setting every pixel to 0xFFFF. This only results in a grey image.This is ofcourse just a test. When loading the actual FITS file, I replace 0xFFFF with `imageArray[i * width + j]`. This works perfectly in 8 bits (of course, I divide every pixel value by 256 to represent it in 8 bits).

```
 NSBitmapImageRep *greyRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:nil
                                                                     pixelsWide:width
                                                                     pixelsHigh:height
                                                                  bitsPerSample:16
                                                                samplesPerPixel:1
                                                                       hasAlpha:NO
                                                                       isPlanar:NO
                                              colorSpaceName:NSCalibratedWhiteColorSpace
                                                                    bytesPerRow:0
                                                                   bitsPerPixel:16];

 NSInteger rowBytes = [greyRep bytesPerRow];
 unsigned short*pix = (unsigned short*)[greyRep bitmapData];
 NSLog(@"Row Bytes: %d",rowBytes);

if(temp.bitPix == 16) // 16 bit image
{
    for(i=0;i<height;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<width;j++)
        {
            pix[i * rowBytes + j] = 0xFFFF;
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried using Quartz2D directly. That does produce a proper image, even in 16 bits. But bizarrely, the data array takes 0xFF as white and not 0xFFFF. So I still have to divide everything by 0xFF - losing data in the process. Quartz2D code:

```
    short* grey = (short*)malloc(width*height*sizeof(short));
    for(int i=0;i<width*height; i++)
    {
        grey[i] = imageArray[i];
    }

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(grey, width, height, 16, width*2, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);
    CFRelease(colorSpace);

    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);

    NSImage *greyImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage size:NSMakeSize(width, height)];
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`initWithData` only works for image types that the system already knows about. For unknown types -- and raw pixel data -- you need to construct the image representation yourself. You can do this via Core Graphics as suggested in the answer that Kirby links to. Alternatively, you can use `NSImage` by creating and adding an `NSBitmapImageRep`.

The exact details will depend on the format of your pixel data, but here's an example of the process for a greyscale image where the source data (the `samples` array) is represented as double in the range [0,1]:

```
/* generate a greyscale image representation */
NSBitmapImageRep *greyRep =
    [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
        initWithBitmapDataPlanes: nil  // allocate the pixel buffer for us
                      pixelsWide: xDim 
                      pixelsHigh: yDim
                   bitsPerSample: 8
                 samplesPerPixel: 1  
                        hasAlpha: NO
                        isPlanar: NO 
                  colorSpaceName: NSCalibratedWhiteColorSpace // 0 = black, 1 = white in this color space
                     bytesPerRow: 0     // passing 0 means "you figure it out"
                    bitsPerPixel: 8];   // this must agree with bitsPerSample and samplesPerPixel

NSInteger rowBytes = [greyRep bytesPerRow];

unsigned char* pix = [greyRep bitmapData];
for ( i = 0; i < yDim; ++i )
{
    for ( j = 0; j < xDim; ++j )
    {
        pix[i * rowBytes + j] = (unsigned char)(255 * (samples[i * xDim + j]));
    }
}

NSImage* greyscale = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(xDim,yDim)];
[greyscale addRepresentation:greyRep];
[greyRep release];
```

---

**EDIT** (in response to comment)

I didn't know for sure whether 16 bit samples were supported, but you seem to have confirmed that they are.

What you're seeing stems from still treating the pixels as `unsigned char`, which is 8 bits. So you're only setting half of each row, and you're setting each of those pixels, one byte at a time, to the two byte value `0xFF00` -- not quite true white, but very close. The other half of the image is not touched, but would have been initialised to 0, so it stays black.

<s>You need instead to work in 16 bit, by first casting the value you get back from the rep:</s>

```
unsigned short * pix = (unsigned short*) [greyRep bitmapData];
```

And then assigning 16 bit values to the pixels:

```
if ( j % 2 )
{
    pix[i * rowBytes + j] = 0xFFFF;
}
else
{
    pix[i * rowBytes + j] = 0;
}
```

Scratch that, `rowBytes` is in bytes so we need to stick with `unsigned char` for `pix` and cast when assigning, which is a bit uglier:

```
if ( j % 2 )
{
    *((unsigned short*) (pix + i * rowBytes + j * 2)) = 0xFFFF;
}
else
{
    *((unsigned short*) (pix + i * rowBytes + j * 2)) = 0;
}
```

(I've switched the order of clauses because the `== 0` seemed redundant. Actually for something like this it would be much neater to use `?:` syntax, but enough of this C futzing.)

Comment: Thank you very very much. My array is just a double and the files can be either 16 or 32 bit. I am assuming, that if its a 16 bit file, I should divide the entire array by 65536 to transform the array such that it only extends from 0 to 1?

Comment: @Saad That's certainly one option. Note that you will lose a fair bit of precision in going from 16 bits to 8 -- that may not matter for your purposes. You can probably specify 16 bit samples when initing the rep, though I haven't tried that and don't know if it would make any observable difference to the displayed result.

Comment: Does the class support 16 bits? I've set bitsPerSample to 16 and bitsPerPixel to 16 as well. However, this code, which should just make an image with alternate black and white columns (it works with your code but not if i change it to 16 bits) just makes an image with the left side white and the right side as black. `if(j%2==0){pix[i * rowBytes + j] = (unsigned char)(0);}else{pix[i * rowBytes + j] = (unsigned char)(255);}`

Comment: @Saad Looks like it does support 16. See update above for explanation of what you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I have everything working when the bitmap is 8 bits/pixel. But if I set it to 16, and make the array a short the image simply does not appear. I just get a black image. (I am using making an NSImage from the bitmap and sending setImage to an ImageView). If I explicitly set every pixel to 0xFFFF the resultant image is not white, but gray. Saving that as a TIFF and opening it in Photoshop confirms its 16 bit, but has a gray value of around 148 or so (PS only reports colour in 8 bit representation). See the edit in my original post for the code.

Comment: @Saad Doh! my code above is wrong because rowBytes is, as the name suggests, in bytes not shorts. This doesn't explain your 16 bit grey issue, which I will need to do some testing to understand. That may take a little while, though - have to sleep now and at a conference for next two days. Hope you find a solution before then, but if not I'll look into it when I get time...

Comment: Wow, okay, I noticed you updated. The new code works perfectly. Can you please elaborate on  `*((unsigned short*) (pix + i * rowBytes + j * 2)) = 0xFFFF`? I haven't seen anything like it before. From trying to pick it apart, I see that you first take the address of pix and then i*rowBytes. This would take us to the appropriate row, I'm guessing? Adding j would take us to the exact pixel we need to be at. But then, why multiply j by 2?

Comment: Okay, I drew a small bitmap on paper and tried to figure out that equation. We multiply j by 2 because we want to access the byte array as a short, right?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution with your code. This was extended to support all 3 channels. Each channel is 16 bits. Note that I assign imageArray[i] to each channel. This is only because I currently haven't written the code which can read colour FITS files, so to test things out I'm just assigning the image to each channel. The result is, of course, a grayscale image on screen. But if one wants, it can easily be modified such that Red is assigned to Red and so on.

```
NSBitmapImageRep *colorRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:nil
                                                                        pixelsWide:width
                                                                        pixelsHigh:height
                                                                     bitsPerSample:16
                                                                   samplesPerPixel:3
                                                                          hasAlpha:NO
                                                                          isPlanar:NO
                                                                    colorSpaceName:NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace
                                                                       bytesPerRow:(3*2*width)
                                                                      bitsPerPixel:48];

    rowBytes = [greyRep bytesPerRow];
    NSLog(@"Row Bytes: %d",rowBytes);
    pix = [colorRep bitmapData];

    for(i=0;i<height*width;++i)
    {
        *((unsigned short*)(pix + 6*i)) = imageArray[i];
        *((unsigned short*)(pix + 6*i + 2)) = imageArray[i];
        *((unsigned short*)(pix + 6*i + 4)) = imageArray[i];
    }


    NSImage *theImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(width, height)];
    [greyScale addRepresentation:colorRep];
    [myimageView setImage:theImage];
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapt the answer from [Converting RGB data into a bitmap in Objective-C++ Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579631/converting-rgb-data-into-a-bitmap-in-objective-c-cocoa) to your data.