# CGBitmapContextCreate returns null; writing rbga pixel array to file

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to write an RBGA pixel array to file using code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579631/converting-rgb-data-into-a-bitmap-in-objective-c-cocoa) [stackoverflow.com], but it fails.

I store my pixel information in a 1-dimensional array of 32-bit integers, so the first bit of this method (hopefully) takes the relevant bits from the 32-bit integer, storing them into an array of chars.

When run, the method below a) prints that we didn't create the image (`CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext)` returned NULL) and b) dies when trying to release the image (`RayTracerProject[33126] <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageDestinationAddImage image parameter is nil`), which makes sense because `cgImage` is null.

The method:

```
-(void) write{

char* rgba = (char*)malloc(width*height);
for(int i=0; i < width*height; ++i) {
    rgba[4*i] = (char)[Image red:pixels[i]];
    rgba[4*i+1] = (char)[Image green:pixels[i]];
    rgba[4*i+2] = (char)[Image blue:pixels[i]];
    rgba[4*i+3] = (char)[Image alpha:pixels[i]];
}
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                                   rgba,
                                                   width,
                                                   height,
                                                   8, // bitsPerComponent
                                                   width, // bytesPerRow
                                                   colorSpace,
                                                   kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);

CFRelease(colorSpace);

CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);

if ( cgImage == NULL ) 
    printf("Couldn't create cgImage correctly"). 

CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("image.png"), kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);

CFStringRef type = kUTTypePNG; // or kUTTypeBMP if you like
CGImageDestinationRef dest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, type, 1, 0);

CGImageDestinationAddImage(dest, cgImage, 0);

CFRelease(cgImage);
CFRelease(bitmapContext);
CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest);
free(rgba);
};
```

For completeness, my bit shifting methods:

```
// Extract the 8-bit red component from a 32bit color integer. 
+(int) red:(int) color{
 return (color >> 16) & 0xff;
};

// Extract the 8-bit green component from a 32bit color integer. 
+(int) green:(int) color{
  return (color >> 8) & 0xff;
};

// Extract the 8-bit blue component from a 32bit color integer. 
+(int) blue:(int) color{
  return (color & 0xff);
};

// Extract the 8-bit alpha component from a 32bit color integer. 
+(int) alpha:(int) color{
  return (color >> 24) & 0xff;
};
```

According to the docs found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454225-cgbitmapcontextcreateimage) [developer.apple.com], `CGBitmapContextCreateImage` will return `A new bitmap context, or NULL if a context could not be created`, but won't help me understand why a context couldn't be created.

What am I doing wrong? [Also, if there is a much smarter way to write a pixel array to file in Objective-C, I'm not tied to this particular way of doing things - this project is a port from a Java one I did a few years ago - I used a FileOutputStream, but can't find an equivalent in Objective-C].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have it working now - posting this in case somebody else finds this useful one day.

There are a few bugs with the code above - I didn't use `width*4` for the bytes per row in the call to `CGBitmapContextCreate`, for example, and my `rgba` array was 4x smaller then it should have been. The code below runs, although I don't know where the image is saved to (I'm going to hardcode a path until I figure it out).

```
-(void) write{

 //printf("First pixel is: %d\n", pixels[0]);
 // RGBA array needs to be 4x pixel array - using 4bytes per int.  
 char* rgba = (char*)malloc(width*height*4);
 //printf("Size of char array: %d\n", width*height*4);

 for(int i=0; i < width*height; ++i) {
    rgba[4*i] = (char)[Image red:pixels[i]];
    rgba[4*i+1] = (char)[Image green:pixels[i]];
    rgba[4*i+2] = (char)[Image blue:pixels[i]];
    rgba[4*i+3] = (char)[Image alpha:pixels[i]];
 }
 CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
 CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                                   rgba,
                                                   width,
                                                   height,
                                                   8, // bitsPerComponent
                                                   width*4, // bytesPerRow (4x larger then width)
                                                   colorSpace,
                                                   kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);

 CFRelease(colorSpace);

 CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);

 /*if ( cgImage == NULL ) 
      printf("Couldn't create cgImage correctly");
  else
      printf("Has been created correctly");
 */
 CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault,  CFSTR("image.png"), kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);

 CFStringRef type = kUTTypePNG; // or kUTTypeBMP if you like
 CGImageDestinationRef dest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, type, 1, 0);

 CGImageDestinationAddImage(dest, cgImage, 0);

 CFRelease(cgImage);
 CFRelease(bitmapContext);
 CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest);
 free(rgba);
};
```

Comment: Don't forget to `free(rgba)`. This can be done after `CGBitmapContextCreateImage` as that is a copy operation.