# UIImage from array

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage

I am working with an API which gives me an image as the example below. I am unsure how I can convert this array of values into an image. I have not seen this before.

Does anyone know how I can make the following array of values into a UIImage?

`[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,1,0,96,...]`

Comment: if it`s public API then mention that API name so someone gives you proper direction. or mention which encoding method use when API send image.

Comment: I am sorry that I cannot give any more information but the API is not public. My hope is that somebody have seen an image represented in this way before.

Comment: it seems like you are getting NSData in the response, have you tried- [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

Comment: i think if it is NSData, the return value will be in bytes, right?

Comment: I don't think it's NSData. When doing `[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]` the application will crash with an `NSInvalidArgumentException`. The response (and the array in the question) is really just an array of integers which I need to interpret.

Comment: it seems that it is a array of bytes... what type of encoding server is using?

Comment: The API returns an XML document which contains a JSON string (not ideal, I know). This JSON string contains the array of integers in the question. The XML document contains the following line, so it seems the encoding is UTF-8, right? `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like straight pixel buffer data, so you will have to guess the format (probably RBGA?) and the image dimensions (hopefully it's fixed/guessable/included in the format).  If you guess correctly you should be able to create a CIImage with CGDataProviderCreateWithData;

```
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, bufferLength, NULL);
//a reasonable guess
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
int bitsPerComponent = 8;
int bitsPerPixel = 32;
int bytesPerRow = 4 * width;

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault, provider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
UIImage *newUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef); 
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
```

Comment: I think that you are right. I'm trying to create a method in which I pass the `NSArray` and a size for the image. Then the method returns the `UIImage`. I'm not sure what to do with the `NSArray`. Can you please tell me how to use it with the code you posted?

Comment: Here is a pretty complete example of the above with buffer creation included: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579631/converting-rgb-data-into-a-bitmap-in-objective-c-cocoa